# Best way to make if statements

Tags: php, if-statement

Basically I am getting values from checkboxes (i.e. how many check boxes checked in a form). What I need to happen is echo a price for a certain number values. Here is what I was thinking but not sure if its the correct way to do it:

```
 $clubTotal = array(
                $driversChecked,
                $hybridsChecked,
                $woodsChecked,
                $boxesChecked,
                $wedgesChecked,
             ); 

 $numberOfclubs = array_sum($total) 

    if ($numberOfclubs > 6)
        echo "price";
    if ($numberOfclubs == 6)
        echo "price";
    if($numberOfclubs > 6 && $numberOfclubs < 9)
        echo "price";
```

I am sure that will work the way I need, just not sure if there is a shorthand or better way to write it. Thanks.

Comment: Change `=` to `==`; you are accidentally assigning rather than comparing.

Comment: Also, your array items need to be separated by commas `,` rather than semi-colons `;`, and the `$wedgesChecked` doesn't need a comma, although php won't complain about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$count = array_sum($clubTotal) ;
if ($count== 6 )
    echo "price when 6" ;
else if ($count> 6)
{
    if ($count< 9)
        echo "price when 7-8" ;
    else
        echo "price when >= 9" ;
}
```

Alternative would be:

```
$count = array_sum($clubTotal) ;
if ( $count >= 6 )
{
    switch( $count )
    {
        case 6:
            echo "price when 6" ;
            break ;

        case 7:
        case 8:
            echo "price when 7-8" ;
            break ;

        default:
            echo "price when >= 9";
            break ;
    }
}
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Using switch is by far the best option. But you dont need break; on a default switch state.

Comment: @Tom That is true, however I do that for safety for future engineers that can work on my code and add new cases at the end of switch. It is almost 30 years experience with working with many people, and from time to time there are people that have 'untidy' programming style.

Comment: @Grzegorz the `(count($clubTotal))` is giving me the count of 5 every time (the number of variables in the array). What I need is the sum of the values in that array. Could I use `if (array_sum($clubTotal))` ??

Comment: Of course. It's my error. Fixing it. Sorry! Done - Notice that your example uses `array_sum($total)` while I think it should use `array_sum($clubTotal)`. Please, confirm.

Comment: @Grzegorz tried it and works like a charm. The Switch seems the best way.

Comment: @Grzegorz would there be a way to store the value echoed in a variable? Like if it echos the default case which is 3.00, can I store the value of what ever case is selected in `$shippingCost` to use in adding to another total? Hope that made sense.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you, but do you think about `ob_start();`, `ob_get_contents();`, and `ob_end_clean()` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38205/discussion-between-packy-and-grzegorz)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`count`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.count.php) function of PHP to count the number of item in your array.

So your code should be like :

```
$numberOfItems = count($clubTotal);
if ($numberOfItems > 6)
        echo "price";
if ($numberOfItems == 6)
         echo "price";
if($numberOfItems > 6 && $numberOfItems < 9)
        echo "price";
```

Comment: First comparison should really by `($numberOfItems >= 9)` unless he want to echo `"price"` twice in certain cases. Regardless, the other `if`s should really by `elseif`s as they are exclusionary.

Comment: I edited the code in main area. Would this work or should I still do the `count($clubTotal);`? @webbiedave I just put "price" in there, each will have their own set price. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't compare an array to integers like that, and the array won't work like that either.

```
$clubTotal = array(
    $driversChecked,
    $hybridsChecked,
    $woodsChecked,
    $boxesChecked,
    $wedgesChecked
);

$count = count($clubTotal);

if( $count > 6 ) {
    echo "price";
}
elseif( $count == 6 ) {
    echo "price";
}
elseif( $count > 6 && $count < 9 ) {
    echo "price";
}
```

You need to count your array items with `count()` and chaining IF statements normally gets the if...elseif... treatment.